# Data returns as "undefined" in Titanium

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, titanium-mobile

I am working on a basic authentication mobile app for iPhone using:

Titanium v. 3.23

XAMPP as my local server and PHP

MySQL as local database

The app I am working on is based off the following tutorial:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/titanium-user-authentication-part-1--mobile-3728

I was able to get the code up and running from the tutorial with no problem, the app allowed me to post a username/password key to my local database, login with the key, and have the information displayed on my main window.

I began to manipulate the code to reflect more of what I am attempting to build, a single window based app (not tab based like in the tutorial) that would allow me to create a username/password key, login to a main window, and on that main window have my information displayed back to me.

I have successfully been able to modify the code to allow me to create a new username/password into my local database, as well as have the app verify if the username/password match upon login. However, when I login to my main screen, it shows that my username and password are "undefined". To check the error, I entered the same user/pass in the project currently holding the working code and it is visible. So I know my current PHP and database are all working correctly.

Currently, my app.js is:

```
setTimeout (function() {

var login;
login = require ('login');
login.LogIn();

var mainWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow();

Ti.App.addEventListener('grantEntrance', function(event){

mainWin.title = 'Welcome ' + event.name;
mainWin.url = 'main.js';
mainWin.name = event.name;
mainWin.email = event.email;

});

}, 2000);
```

The setTimeout function is to eventually be a splash screen which I added independent from the tutorial above. I also changed the "main" items to reflect my mainWin, rather than the "main" as indicated in the tutorial.

Currently, my login.js is:

```
function LogIn(){

var loginWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor:'white'
});

var username = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
color:'#336699',
top:10,
left:10,
width:300,
height:40,
hintText:'Username',
keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT,
borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});
loginWin.add(username);

var password = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
color:'#336699',
top:60,
left:10,
width:300,
height:40,
hintText:'Password',
passwordMask:true,
keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT,
borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});
loginWin.add(password);

var loginBtn = Titanium.UI.createButton({
title:'Login',
top:110,
width:90,
height:35,
borderRadius:1,
font:{fontFamily:'Arial',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:14}
});
loginWin.add(loginBtn);

var createLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
text:'Create Profile',
bottom: 25,
left:25
});
loginWin.add(createLabel);

var indicatorWin = Ti.UI.createView({
width: 320,
height: 480,
backgroundColor: '#000000',
opacity: 0.5
});

var acctInd = Ti.UI.createActivityIndicator({
height:50,
width:50,
style: Titanium.UI.createActivityIndicatorStyle.Plain,
top:250,
left:130
});

var actLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
text: 'Checking Login Details',
color: '#FFFFFF',
left:70,
top:200,
height:50

});

indicatorWin.hide();
acctInd.hide();
actLabel.hide():

loginWin.add(indicatorWin);
indicatorWin.add(acctInd);
indicatorWin.add(actLabel);

var loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

loginReq.onload = function()
{
var json = this.responseText;

var response = JSON.parse(json);

if (response.logged == true)

{
    username.blur();
    password.blur(); 

    Ti.App.fireEvent('grantEntrance', {
        name:response.name,
        email:response.email
    });
    loginWin.close();
        var main;
        main = require ('main');
        main.MainM();
}
else
{
    alert(response.message);
}
};

loginBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e)

{  
if (username.value != '' && password.value != '')

{

    loginReq.open("POST","http://localhost/Tuts/post_auth.php");

    var params = {
        username: username.value,
        password: Ti.Utils.md5HexDigest(password.value)
    };

    loginReq.send(params);

    indicatorWin.show();
    acctInd.show();
    actLabel.show();
}  
else
{
    alert("Username/Password are required");
}
});

createLabel.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
var ProfileWin, ProfileInc;
ProfileInc = require ('createProfile');
ProfileWin = new ProfileInc.CreateP();
ProfileWin.open();
});

loginWin.open();
return ;loginWin;
}
exports.LogIn=LogIn;
```

Currently, my main.js is:

```
function MainM(){

var mainWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
backgroundColor:'white'
});

var msg = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
text:"\n\nYour email is:\n" + mainWin.email + "\n\nyour name is:\n" + mainWin.name,
top:10,
left:10,
width:300,
height:'auto'
});
mainWin.add(msg);

mainWin.open();
return ;mainWin;
}
exports.MainM=MainM;
```

As you can see I haven't changed much, if anything, to the actual database section of the app. Which is why I am confused that it isn't working. The only research I have found indicated that there might be a problem with an asynchronous request and heard that by using a setTimeout function i might be able to get around my error. I have attempted to insert the function in a few places however the error still persists.

Sorry so long, I have been working on this for a month and I wanted to be as detailed as possible.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If possible, I'd rewrite this app in Alloy. Why? 1) The window.url property will be deprecated soon and is not best practice now. So, your app will stop working once that happens. 2) Common.js modules are much easier to pass data between using the args[0] object. Just some thoughts hopefully to make the learning curve a little less steep. good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code,  main screen is a new Window, which does not have access to the variables email and name.

What you can do to fetch the values in the min win is either Save them in [Properties](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties) and use them, or modify your main.js .

Comment: Thanks Dragon! That makes perfect sense. If I wanted to modify my main.js, would I need to write an entirely new PHP file to get the information? Or could I call it using the same files I currently have and just modify the Titanium code?

Comment: you can just modify the Titanium code, use Properties to save the email and name and fetch them inside main.js do something like this
`Titanium.App.Properties.setString("name",response.name);`
inside your login.js and fetch them at main.js
`Titanium.App.Properties.getString("name");`

Comment: Thanks again Dragon! You are correct, using the 'Titanium.App.Properties' worked. Unfortunately I should have been a bit more specific in my question. I apologize. In my main.js, I am wanting to recall other information in addition to the username/password. I was able to use the 'Titanium.App.Properties.getString' successfully and display the username/password key, but not other fields such as email. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to Print json that you receive from server and see if email is present in it.

Comment: @Mike S. I might have gone above my learning curve here. I do eventually want to transfer it over to Alloy, however for a school project we were asked to initially do something basic to begin with, so I might be bound to the classic mode until the 2nd part of the project.

Comment: Would it be possible to keep the authentication part as is and create a function in my main.js file that might be able to execute automatically on opening? Or, for starters, if I were to add a button in my main.js, could I code an event listener to allow me to retrieve the information I want from my database?